# How to create object which can be modified by multiple angular2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to create object which can be modified by multiple angular2 component.

Eg.

**PeopleService.ts**

```
//a simple service
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor() {
    this.people = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Brad'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Jules'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Jeff'}
    ];
}
  changeBrad(){
    this.people[0].name = "Brad_Changed";
  }
}
```

**App.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {PeopleService} from './peopleService';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  bindings: [PeopleService]
})
@View({
  template: '{{appval}}',
})
export class App{
  appval:string;
  constructor(public peopleService:PeopleService){
    peopleService.changeBrad();
    this.appval = peopleService.people[0].name; // result : Brad_Changed
  }
}
```

**Home.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {PeopleService} from './peopleService';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  bindings: [PeopleService]
})
@View({
  template: '{{homeval}}',
})
export class Home{
  homeval:string;
  constructor(public peopleService:PeopleService){
    this.homeval = peopleService.people[0].name; // result : Brad
  }
}
```

In Home.ts result is " Brad" which is not modified by App.ts I want result to be "Brad_Changed" which was modified by App.ts. How do I write my PeopleService.ts and how to pass it by reference to other component in angular2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `PeopleService` from `Home` component bindings. By adding this binding, you're creating new instance of `PeopleService` for `Home` component and all its children:

```
import {Component, View, Host} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {PeopleService} from './peopleService';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  // Adding this you're creating new instance of PeopleService for
  // Home component and all its children
  // bindings: [PeopleService]
})
@View({
  template: '<p>{{homeval}}</p>',
})
export class Home{
  homeval:string;
  constructor(peopleService:PeopleService){
    this.homeval = peopleService.people[0].name; // result : Brad
  }
}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/usoNlHp4bcMqdrheybGj?p=preview)